Sort xml sub-tree by element text
enter image description here
<Awmds>
    <General_segment>
    <Bol_segment>
    ...
    <Bol_sgement>
        <Bol_id>
        <Bol_reference>GOSUBOM6440660</Bol_reference>
        <Line_number>5</Line_number>
        <Bol_nature>23</Bol_nature>
         ...

Look for online tool
It can sort <Bol_segment> sub-tree based on value of <Bol_reference>.

I think this question is on-topic
